# TDictionary strange behaviour in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following issue:

I'm populating a Dictionary with some values and would like to get them back in the same exact order I populated them.

Somehow it doesn't seem to be working, when I iterate through items they are sorted by a non logic order (IMDO).

Once the following program is run:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;
var
  Dictionary: TDictionary<LongWord, string>;
  aPair: TPair<LongWord, string>;
begin
  Dictionary := TDictionary<LongWord, string>.Create;
  Dictionary.add(1, 'First Item');
  Dictionary.add(2, 'Second Item');
  Dictionary.add(3, 'Third Item');
  Dictionary.add(4, 'Forth Item');
  Dictionary.add(5, 'Fifth Item');
  Dictionary.add($FFFFFFFF, 'Longword Item');

  for aPair in Dictionary do
    writeln(aPair.Value);

  readln;
end.
```

I got the following results:

```
Forth Item
Longword Item
First Item
Third Item
Second Item
Fifth Item
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Tested on XE5 and Rad Studio Berlin, same results.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Delphi dictionary class is unordered. It behaves as designed. If you wish to maintain the order then you need to use an ordered data structure. For instance an array or a list.

If you wish to have ordered access as well as O(1) lookup then you would need to maintain two collections in tandem. One an array or list for ordered access, and in tandem a dictionary for O(1) lookup. Or, alternatively, find a library that offers an ordered dictionary implementation.

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate!

Comment: A bit tricky but it's what I was thinking to manage it when you first replied me. Is there any reason it's designed like that?

Comment: The implementation for O(1) lookup in this case is based on hashes and buckets. And that does not lend itself naturally to maintaining an order. Since this collection is designed for random access by unordered key why implement more functionality to support random access by ordered key?